# Как заполнить поле input type="time" в Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Проект Spring-Boot + Thymeleaf
При открытии формы html не заполняется данными поле input type="time"
Причем вот так работает:

```html
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation} required>
```

а вот так:

```html
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:field="*{timeOperation}" required>
```

или так:

```html
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:field="*{timeOperation}" th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation} required>
```

поле остается пустым.
Вот код формы записи методом POST:

```html
<form id="f-03" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/car/edit/{id}(id=${carEntity.getId()})}" th:object="${carEntity}">
  <input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputTime" th:value=${CarEntity.timeOperation} required>
  <button type="submit" value="save">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так а что не заполняется-то? Нажимаете "Выполнить код", кликаете левой кнопкой мыши на иконку часов - и выбираете время.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В первом варианте данные из переменной заносятся в поле ввода, но не записываются, при нажатии на кнопку "Запись" в эту переменную когда пользователь изменил время. Я добавил остальной код формы. А во втором и третьем случае все наоборот, данные записываются, но не считываются